# How to calculate $||V||_2^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a $1\times n$ vector $V$ and $m \times n$ matrix $W$. How do I calculate $||V||_2^2 $ and $||W||_F^2$ ?

I'm not really sure what F stands for.

Comment: Are you sure $V$ is a vector? $\|\cdot\|_F$ usually stands for the Frobenius norm, which is a matrix norm.

Comment: @user1551 you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is an $n$-vector, $\|V\|_2$ is its Eucliedan 2-norm, i.e. $\|V\|_2=\sqrt{|v_1|^2+\ldots+|v_n|^2}$.

For an $m\times n$ matrix $W$, $\|W\|_F$ denotes its Frobenius norm
$$
\|W\|_F = \sqrt{\sum_i\sum_j|w_{ij}|^2},
$$
which is actually a Euclidean 2-norm when $W$ is viewed as a vector. Strictly speaking, if $\operatorname{vec}(W)$ is the *vector* of length $mn$ formed by stacking the columns of $W$ together, i.e.
$$\operatorname{vec}(W)=(w_{11},\ldots,w_{m1},w_{12},\ldots,w_{m2},\ldots,w_{1n},\ldots,w_{mn})^T,$$
then $\|W\|_F=\|\operatorname{vec}(W)\|_2$. The Frobenius norm is *not* denoted by $\|\cdot\|_2$ because for matrices, the notation $\|\cdot\|_2$ is reserved for the *operator norm induced by the 2-norm*:
$$\|W\|_2 = \max\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\,\|x\|_2=1}\|Wx\|_2.$$
(When $W$ is a square matrix, $\|W\|_2$ is also known as the *spectral norm*.)

Comment: thank you, can you also include in your answer the superscript 2? Does it just mean to square the who expression, thereby cancelling out the square root? W is not a vector stack.

Comment: @bizso09 Yes, the superscript simply denotes the square of a quantity, as in $3^2=9$ or $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$. And I don't understand what the phrase "$W$ is not a vector stack" refers to.

Comment: Okay, I meant that W is not a flattened matrix

Answer (score 1):

$\|V\|_2^2$ is the square of the euclidian Norm so 
$$\|V\|_2^2=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2 $$ 
$\|V\|_F$ could be the frobeniusnorm, which ist for $m=1$ equivalent to the $\|\cdot \|_2$ norm so it would be 
$$\|V\|_F^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2$$

Comment: Thank you sir. You saved me so much pain, you don't even know.

Comment: And what is $m$? Then number of columns?

Comment: oh i am sorry, the frobeniusnorm is a matrix norm and for $A\in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ it is defined as $$\|A\|_F=\left( \sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| \right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: yes, actually the second case may be a matrix indeed, not a vector. my fault

Comment: This is not the definition given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm You miss a square. So the equality of the two norms is trivial.

Comment: I have rephrased the question with the second part being a matrix, not a vector

Comment: yeah in face I forgot the square i am afraid i changed it

Comment: Note that equivalent means something very precise when dealing with norms. And it does not mean equality.